# Automapper to map Container to Containee

Tags: .net, automapper

I'm kinda new to Automapper so I might try to use it for something it shouldn't be used for, but here it goes. I have two classes :

```
  public class Container
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string StrVal { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Containee Containee { get; set; }
    }  

  public class Containee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string DifferentStr { get; set; }
        public DateTime birthday { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have a DTO that looks like this :

```
  public class ContaineeDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string DifferentStr { get; set; }
        public DateTime birthday { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is to use Automapper to map my Container to my ContaineeDTO. I feel like this should use a resolver, especially for passing Code from the Container to the Containee DTO, but I'm unsure about how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this configuration in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Container, ContaineeDTO>()
   .ForMember(containeeDto => containeeDto.Value, opt => 
       opt.MapFrom(container => container.Containee.Value))
   .ForMember(containeeDto => containeeDto.DifferentStr, opt => 
       opt.MapFrom(container => container.Containee.DifferentStr))
   .ForMember(containeeDto => containeeDto.birthday, opt => 
       opt.MapFrom(container => container.Containee.birthday));
```

**Important** note: you named properties same in two classes, so there is no necessity to provide their names in mapping definition (as you see, I didn't do it)

Comment: Okay, but let's assume these aren't the actual objects and that Container and Containee have completely different properties, Containee and ContaineeDTO have the same properties, except that Containee DTO has the field Code from Container, would that still work ?

Comment: So why are you posting classes with different properties that you have in code...? No, it won't work, because it means that `ContaineeDTO` will have some unmapped properties, since `Container` has different properties than `ContaineeDTO`

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm posting classes that are the ones I'm working on for confidentiality reasons, I'll update my post to try to be more like the actual case I'm working on.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer - I hope you will understand after reading it, how to map your classes

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So, there's no way to simply return the ContaineeDTO (even if I already have a mapping from Containee to ContaineeDTO) and just update the Code property from the Dto, I'll have to map each property one by one ?

Comment: No, unless you would move `Code` from `Container` to `Containee`. Then it would be enough to just `Map<Containee, ContaineeDTO>()` (we would completely ignore mapping from `Container` scenario)